# Function definition with one argument as index

Tags: isabelle

This question is somewhat related to [function with index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725626/function-definition-with-index-subscripts)

Imagine the definition of the function is

```
definition myf :: "nat => nat => nat" where
  "myf n a = n * a"
```

and I want to use a more readable abbreviation

```
"f<sub>n</sub> a"
```

instead of

```
"myf n a"
```

I have tried

```
definition myf :: "nat => nat => nat" **("f<sub>_</sub> _" [90])** where
  "f<sub>n</sub> a = n * a"
```

and I get the error
Head of definition "f<sub>n</sub>" differs from declaration "myf".

How am I supposed to write the prefix s.t. it gives me what I am looking for?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscripts that span a region of text can be marked up with `\<^bsub>`...`\<^esub>` (or, equivalently, `⇘`...`⇙`). Therefore, your definition should be as follows:

```
definition myf :: "nat => nat => nat" ("f⇘_⇙") where
  "f⇘n⇙ a = n * a"
```

For further information see Appendix B in [The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2022/doc/isar-ref.pdf).

Comment: Thank you @JavierDiaz - that did solve my immediate issue. 

I am not sure what "region of text" translates to in this case, I'll dig a bit more to understand the link between an argument as subscript/superscript and this special markup.

Comment: @AliciaM.: "Region of text" means any valid expression, in your case, any expression of type `nat` that you can pass as argument to your function, e.g., you can write `f⇘Suc (Suc 0)⇙`. This distinction is made since, in addition, there is the markup `⇧` and `⇩` for _fixed_, single-character superscripts and subscripts, respectively. P.S.: Since my answer effectively answered your original question, I kindly ask you to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: perfect explanation, thank you... I missed the fact that you can have an expression as the argument, that makes perfect sense, ofc. Thanks, again!